# Int is unreacheable inside its own class

Tags: int

So I am helping a friend with a programming question and neither of us can see why the amountBurger, amountChickenSandwich, amountTaco, amountNachos, or amountFries are unreachable in `toString()` at the bottom of the code

```
'''/*

 *

 */
package edu.ilstu;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * <tracks the amount of all orders for the day>
 *
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class OrderClass
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static final double BURGER = 5.00;
    public static final double FRIES = 2.50;
    public static final double TACO = 2.00;
    public static final double NACHOS = 6.50;
    public static final double CHICKEN_SANDWICH = 5.25;
    public static final double SMALL_DRINK = 1.25;
    public static final double MEDIUM_DRINK = 1.75;
    public static final double LARGE_DRINK = 2.25;

    private double price;
    private int amountBurger, amountFries, amountTaco, amountNachos, amountChickenSandwich, amountSmallDrink, amountMediumDrink, amountLargeDrink, count;
    private boolean delivery;

    public void order(int amountBurger, int amountFries, int amountTaco, int amountNachos, int amountChickenSandwich, int amountSmallDrink, int amountMediumDrink, int amountLargeDrink)
    {

    }
    public void orderPrice()
    {
        this.price = amountBurger * BURGER + amountFries * FRIES + amountTaco * TACO + amountNachos * NACHOS + amountChickenSandwich * CHICKEN_SANDWICH + amountSmallDrink * SMALL_DRINK + amountMediumDrink * MEDIUM_DRINK + amountLargeDrink * LARGE_DRINK;
    }

    public int getAmountBurger()
    {
        return amountBurger;
    }
    public void setAmountBurger(int amountBurger)
    {
        this.amountBurger = amountBurger;
    }
    public int getAmountFries()
    {
        return amountFries;
    }
    public void setAmountFries(int amountFries)
    {
        this.amountFries = amountFries;
    }
    public int getAmountTaco()
    {
        return amountTaco;
    }
    public void setAmountTaco(int amountTaco)
    {
        this.amountTaco = amountTaco;
    }
    public int getAmountNachos()
    {
        return amountNachos;
    }
    public void setAmountNachos(int amountNachos)
    {
        this.amountNachos = amountNachos;
    }
    public int getAmountChickenSandwich()
    {
        return amountChickenSandwich;
    }
    public void setAmountChickenSandwich(int amountChickenSandwich)
    {
        this.amountChickenSandwich = amountChickenSandwich;
    }
    public int getAmountSmallDrink()
    {
        return amountSmallDrink;
    }
    public void setAmountSmallDrink(int amountSmallDrink)
    {
        this.amountSmallDrink = amountSmallDrink;
    }
    public int getAmountMediumDrink()
    {
        return amountMediumDrink;
    }
    public void setAmountMediumDrink(int amountMediumDrink)
    {
        this.amountMediumDrink = amountMediumDrink;
    }
    public int getAmountLargeDrink()
    {
        return amountLargeDrink;
    }
    public void setAmountLargeDrink(int amountLargeDrink)
    {
        this.amountLargeDrink = amountLargeDrink;
    }
    public boolean getDelivery()
    {
        return delivery;
    }
    public void setDelivery(boolean delivery)
    {
        this.delivery = delivery;
    }
    public void count()
    {
        this.count= count + 1;
    }
    public String toString(int orderSelection)
    {

        if(orderSelection == 1)
        {
            return "Burger - $5.00" + "\nHow many do you want? ";

            //amountBurger = scan.nextInt();

        }
        else if(orderSelection == 2)
        {
            return "Chicken Sandwich - $5.25" + "\nHow many do you want? ";
            amountChickenSandwich = scan.nextInt();
        }
        else if(orderSelection == 3)
        {
            return "Taco - $2.00" + "\nHow many do you want? ";
            amountTaco = scan.nextInt();
        }
        else if(orderSelection == 4)
        {
            return "Nachos - $6.50" + "\nHow many do you want? ";
            amountNachos = scan.nextInt();
        }
        else
        {
            return "Fries - $2.50" + "\nHow many do you want? ";
            amountFries = scan.nextInt();
        }      
    }


} '''
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you use the `return` keyword. When the compiler sees `return`, it immediately takes that value, goes back to where the function was called, and ignores the rest of the function.

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do here, but if you're trying to ask for the next prompt (how many whatevers do you want?) you need to do that from where `toString` is called.